# Can "domine" be used to refer to a woman?

Tags: phrase-usage, grammatical-gender

In my native language God is named "Dumnezeu" which comes from Latin "Domine Deus". [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/domine) indicates that "Domine" is still being used in English (or at least a dictionary contains it) meaning:

> 1. Lord; master.
> 2. A clergyman; especially a settled minister or parson.

So there is no clear indication that domine refers to a man (male person) only.

**Question:** Can "domine" be used to refer to a woman?

Comment: The first sense is clearly reserved for men, since a woman would be a lady, nor a lord. According to Wikipedia, the second sense is synonymous with pre-Reformation parsons, so that would also be limited to men (since women could not hold such office in those days). More importantly, though, I would say that the word is **not** still being used in English in either of these senses. Some dictionaries include them, others don’t; those that do generally mark them as _archaic_ or _obsolete_. I had personally never heard the word before (except as a Latin vocative).

Comment: (Note: Some dictionaries, like Merriam-Webster, has _domine_ as an archaic variant of _dominie_, which is still occasionally used, though that too is quite rare and old-fashioned, unless you happen to be a member of the Dutch Reformed Church. And _domine_ is also the name of a fish, apparently, in which sense I imagine it’s still in common enough use if you live in a place where the fish is common.)

Comment: In Latin it would surely be _domina_ if referring to a woman.